# How can I paint and animate a mask with the new Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

does anyone know how to paint (and animate) a mask within the new Grease Pencil (Blender 2.8) ?

I guess that it should be possible to either define a Grease Pencil layer as mask; or to use an holdout material or something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Using *Subtract* as a Blend mode for a Grease Pencil layer acts just like a mask:

[image]

Subtracted layers will act as holdout for every other layer that is listed below them, but regardless of their view-depth (layers in front are masked out too). Layers in other GP objects are not affected

[image]

Comment: Seems perfect but it is not working here (2.8 beta), don't know why ?  I use a black material like you, my GP layer blend mode is set to "substract" too.  And I get this : https://imgur.com/a/rM5Rxky

Comment: is it the top layer and in the same object? it should work.. keep in mind the feature was added in the last month so you need an updated beta

Comment: Got the last nighlty.  Maybe you need a background color for this to work ? (not working on transparent) ?

Comment: The contents of a subtract layer become visible wherever they don't overlay with the contents of other layers. This is quite different from the behaviour of masks in other graphics/animation software. Is there any way to have the contents of a masking layer be invisible in all cases, but still mask other layers when they overlap?